# Pandas/Python Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to find the string in a pandas dataframe (which could be numeric or spelled) next to the string "years of experience" which could be spelled differently.

My code is:
`for string in df['columns']:
match = re.findall('((E|e)xperience|(E|e)xp)+\\s?(of|:)+\\s?([a-zA-Z]|\\d|\\d\\+|\\d+\\s?\\-\\s?\\d+|\\d+\\s?to\\s?\\d+\\+?)+\\s+((y|Y)(ear|r))\\(s??\\)',string)`

But I've been running into a lot of strange unterminated subpattern errors, or constants.error:missing errors and I'm not sure why.

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Comment: I think you're over-escaping, i tend to write the patern I want in a `r'pattern'` string

Comment: could you give an Example of what's actually needs to be matched, and where it is going wrong?

Comment: So the string tends to be "5 years of experience required" or "five years of experience required" and I want to pull the number "5" or "five".

When I execute the code bit by bit, I can find the elements.
For e.g: match = re.findall((y|Y)(ear|r),string) yields a list with ['y','ear'] and re.search with the same expression yields a match result for "year".

But when I mesh more elements or execute the whole code together, the code simply prints "None" (re.search) or a blank list (re.findall), or errors or it won't even run.

Comment: remember that a + matches 1 or more instances of the previous pattern (eg `\d+` matches 1 or 11 or 12345, and that the whole pattern has to match for you to get results. Maybe you want to swap some of those + for *?

Comment: Hmm...do you have any sample code that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the regex is faulty:

```
\\(s??\\)
```

Simply removing it improves the results.  The new regex:

```
((E|e)xperience|(E|e)xp)+\\s?(of|:)+\\s?([a-zA-Z]|\\d|\\d\\+|\\d+\\s?\\-\\s?\\d+|\\d+\\s?to\\s?\\d+\\+?)+\\s+((y|Y)(ear|r))
```

#From your summary, I created the following test cases:

```
testCases = [
"this string is not valid for 5 years",
"i am very good worker with 3 months of experience",
"While working I have Years of experience: 5. ",
"This Years of experience: 5. Also good at text formatting",
"My brother that is 7 years old. This Years experience: 5. ",
"months of experience: 5.",
"Experiance: 5 months",
"Experiance: many years",
"Experience: 3 years and 2 months",
"After I did two years experience in data science",
"After I did two yrs experience in data science"]
```

When testing the new regex, I see only one line matches & provides a list of values.  It is not clear which item in the list is the years' experience number.

```
for string in testCases:
    match = re.findall('((E|e)xperience|(E|e)xp)+\\s?(of|:)+\\s?([a-zA-Z]|\\d|\\d\\+|\\d+\\s?\\-\\s?\\d+|\\d+\\s?to\\s?\\d+\\+?)+\\s+((y|Y)(ear|r))',string)
    if match != []:
        print("Found:",string)
```

Prints out:

```
Experience: 3 years and 2 months
```

I'd follow a different approach. First I'd search for partial strings that should exist

```
checkList = {}
checkList['experiencePartialStrings'] = ['experi']
checkList['yearsPartialStrings'] = ['yr','year']
```

If these do not exist, then simply ignore the text

I split the string into words using split() & check the distance between the number & the word years. I also check the distance between experience & years

```
maxWordDistanceBetweenExperienceAndYears = 4
maxWordDistanceBetweenYearsAndNumber = 4
```

Eliminating written numbers with an equivalenceDict. :

```
numberEquivalenceDict = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5,'six':6,'seven':7,'eight':8,'nine':9,'ten':10}

def GetYearsExperience(testCase):
    #Let's not worry about case:
    testCase = testCase.lower()
    #Replace punctuation with spaces
    testCase = re.sub('\W',' ',testCase)
    testCaseList = testCase.split()
    #Replace the number words with numbers:
    testCaseList = [numberEquivalenceDict[i] if i in numberEquivalenceDict.keys() else i for i in testCaseList]    
    experienceDict = {}
    experienceDict['numbersIndexes'] = []
    experienceDict['yearsIndex'] = None
    experienceDict['experienceWordIndex'] = None
    yearsExperience = None
    
    testCaseSet = set(testCaseList)
    for i,word in enumerate(testCaseList):
        word = str(word)
        if 'exper' in word:
            #if the word experience comes up multiple times, only the last one will be considered
            experienceDict['experienceWordIndex'] = i
        for yearString in ['yr','year']:
            #if the year comes up multiple times, only the last one will be considered
            if yearString in word:
                experienceDict['yearsIndex'] = i
        try:
            int(word)
            experienceDict['numbersIndexes'].append(i)
        except:
                pass
    if experienceDict['numbersIndexes'] == [] or \
        experienceDict['yearsIndex'] == None or \
        experienceDict['experienceWordIndex'] == None:
            return None
    elif abs(experienceDict['yearsIndex'] - experienceDict['experienceWordIndex']) > 4:
        
        return None
    #First consider the easy case where there is only one number
    if len(experienceDict['numbersIndexes']) == 1:
        if abs(experienceDict['yearsIndex'] - experienceDict['numbersIndexes'][0])<=4:
            return int(testCaseList[experienceDict['numbersIndexes'][0]])
    #Consider the case where multiple numbers exist. Use the one closest to years
    else:
        previousDistance = 1000
        for numberIndex in experienceDict['numbersIndexes']:
            distance = abs(experienceDict['yearsIndex'] - numberIndex)
            if distance < previousDistance:
                yearsExperience = int(testCaseList[numberIndex])
                previousDistance = distance
        return yearsExperience


experienceList = []
print("Result & testCase")
for testCase in testCases:
    yearsExperience = GetYearsExperience(testCase)
    print([yearsExperience,testCase])
```

> Result & testCase

```
[None, 'this string is not valid for 5 years']
[None, 'i am very good worker with 3 months of experience']
[5, 'While working I have Years of experience: 5. ']
[5, 'This Years of experience: 5. Also good at text formatting']
[5, 'My brother that is 7 years old. This Years experience: 5. ']
[None, 'months of experience: 5.']
[None, 'Experiance: 5 months']
[None, 'Experiance: many years']
[3, 'Experience: 3 years and 2 months']
[2, 'After I did two years experience in data science']
[2, 'After I did two yrs experience in data science']
```